# ASP.NET Core MVC : how to add a link to a view in another folder

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC application. Inside the `Views` folder, there are an `Employees` and a `Salaries` folder.

I want to add a link on the `Index` page of the `Employees` folder to the `Index` page of `Salaries`.

Here's the part of the markup with the links.

```
<td>
    <a asp-page="/Salaries/Index" asp-route-id="@item.Id">View Salary Components</a> |
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
</td>
```

This is the route mapping in `Program.cs`:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Nothing happens when I click the "View Salary Components" link. How can I add the link correctly?

There are answers which explain how to redirect to a view in another folder inside the controller but I couldn't find an answer with a link.

Comment: What's your Program.cs route like ?  Where is  your  Employees and Salaries folder behind ?

Comment: @Qing Guo I have edited the question with the answer to your question.

Comment: Is your Index page of Salaries a razor page or view ?

Comment: @Qing Guo A view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a razor page:

Try to modify the route in Program.cs like:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
...
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Besides, make sure the structure like:

[image]

For a mvc view:

Try to use `asp-controller`

```
<a asp-controller="Salaries" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@item.Id">View Salary Components</a> |
```

Note views are typically returned from actions as a ViewResult, so we need to create an action to call the view, you can read [Views in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-8.0)  to know more.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Adding the asp-controller worked. Thanks!